# How can I replicate this console action in VB.net with Webview2?

Tags: vb.net, webview2

So in edge I F12, goto console and type in SM.Player.token and receive a value back, not sure what you call this - a javascript variable or function?

I've got a program that does various interactions with this page and whilst I can manually go into the console, retrieve this value and enter it into a text box in the app it would be nice to be able to automate this part of the process.

I tried :

```
Dim token As String = ""
Dim script As String = "document.getElementById('SM.Player.token')"
token = "" & WebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(script).ToString
```

But that just returns :

"System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]"

Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this will be all you need, so I won't post it as an answer, but you need to await that async method: `Dim token = await WebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(script)`. The return type of the method is `Task(Of String)` so awaiting it will get the `String` result of that `Task`.

Comment: Are you sure that `getElementById` is what you need there? Is there actually an element in the HTML that has an `id` of `'SM.Player.token'`? I'm guessing not. Even if there was, I would think that you'd then have to get the content of that element or the value of an attribute.

Comment: Is this a public URL that you're visiting? If so, can you share it?

Comment: >> Are you sure that getElementById is what you need there?  - No, not sure, I access this "token" using the console window, think this is a javascript method but not sure

Comment: It's an online game called splinterlands - https://splinterlands.com/ - My program is tracking my games and showing win rates based on cards used to play. There was a recent change that required the token to be able to access the API data required to view the match data. You need to be logged in to actually get a token though so unless you play you'll not be able to check it out

Comment: You do need to await the result of ExecuteScriptAsync. But also just returning a DOM element through ExecuteScriptAsync won't do what you want. You probably want to do `document.getElementById("SM.Player.Token").textContent` or `document.getElementById("SM.Player.Token").innerHTML` in order to get the contents of that element. Try running the script in the DevTools console to see if the result is what you expect.